# CometD data not reaching client

Tags: javascript, java, cometd

I have two client applications that use CometD to talk to a server. My server sends some data to my clients using the deliver() method of the ServerSession. The data is in the form of a string.

One of my applications is a Javascript- based web application. I can access the data delivered by the server in the following manner:

```
function(theMsg) {
  alert(theMsg.data);
}
```

This works well as a callback for when I want to send data on a particular channel.

Unfortunately, my second application is a Java application whose callback does not seem able to get the data. The callback works as follows:

```
public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message)
{
    String data = (String )theMsg.getData();
    System.out.println("Data "+data);
}
```

The problem here is that the getData() for some reason returns a null in Java. I cannot seem to find any way to get at the data that I sent from the server!

Is there some kind of bug in the java CometD API, or am I using the wrong function to get the data that I am sending from the server? How can I get at this data?

Someone please advise...

Addition 1: below is the first client, implemented in Javascript, as requested by sbordet. This client works...

```
var cometD = $.cometd;

var isConnected = false;

var rcvHandshake = function(hndValue) {
    console.log("Received handshake. Success flag is " + hndValue.successful);
}

var amConnected = function(msgConnect) {
    if(cometD.isDisconnected())
    {
        isConnected = false;
        console.log("Server connection not established!");
    }
    else
    {
        var prevconnected = mySelf.isConnected;

        // This checks whether or not the connection was actually successful
        isConnected = msgConnect.successful === true;
        if((prevconnected == false) && (isConnected == true))
        {
            console.log("Connected to the server!");
            cometD.addListener("/service/output",updateOutput);
        }
        else if((prevconnected == true) && (isConnected == false))
        {
            console.log("Connection to server has ended!")
        }
    }

}

var startUp = function() {
    console.log("Starting up...");

    var cometURL = $(location).attr('origin') + "/tester/cometd";
     cometD.configure({
        url: cometURL,
        logLevel: 'info'
    });

    cometD.addListener('/meta/handshake',rcvHandshake);
    cometD.addListener('/meta/connect',amConnected);

    cometD.handshake({
        "thehash.autohash": "foo-bar-baz-hash"
    });

}

var updateOutput = function(theOut) {
    alert(theOut.data);
}
```

Comment: Please show the full code you use in both JavaScript and Java. The CometD library has the concept of a _message callback_ that is used to get a reply from the server that the message reached the server, and the concept of a _message listener/subscriber_ that is used to receive messages received from the server. Without the complete client code, it's not clear what you refer to. You may be using the right API in JavaScript, and the wrong one in Java.

Comment: Okaaaay... I am pretty aware of CometD's message concept, and the client code for both languages is pretty standard and straightforward (I think). I will nevertheless add the code as requested...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I was looking over my Java code in order to format it for posting to this Question, when I noticed a typo in the channel names that I was listening for. I corrected the typo, which included a channel that I was using to publish requests to the server (apparently the listener I was using was activated before the data was returned), and as a result the getData() method was empty.

Sending the data to the correct channel solved the problem. My getData() method no longer returns null.

Sorry I bugged people about such a ridiculously amateurish mistake. I will try to avoid this sort of thing in future.

Special thanks to sbordet for requesting the full code, which caused me to re- examine it and find my typo...